# How to pass value from controller to view in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I tried two options (which could find in internet) and no progress:

```
//in controller
$show_all = TRUE;
$view->assignRef('show', $show_all);
//in default.php and viev.html.php
$this->show;
//result
Notice: Undefined property: componentViewcomponent::$show


//in controller
$show_all = TRUE;
$view->assign('show', $show_all);
//in default.php and viev.html.php
$this->get('show');
//result
NULL
```

Comment: Try to use "true" or some integer values that may fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$model  = $this->getModel('mymodel'); //get the model
$data_list = $model->getSomeData();//get data from the model
$view = $this->getView('view_name', 'html'); // get the view
$view->assignRef('data_list', $data_list); // set the data to the view
$view->display(); // show the view
```

This is what I have been using for past 1 year and it always works for me.

Comment: `$view->display();` helped. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Problem appeared. When i'm trying to use `$model = $this->getModel();` in my view i get `Notice: Undefined index:`. It is because i'm using yours suggested `$view->display();` instead of `parent::display()` in controller. How you solved this problem?

Comment: you have to specify the name of the model.$this->getModel('model_name');